# What kind of for loop is this?

Tags: c#

Is there a special name for this type of for loop in c#?

```
for (EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); eventdetail != null; eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
```

EDIT: I'm trying to research if there is a way to do this in a multithreaded way. since `Parallel.For` can't be called in the same fashion I was hoping there was a special name for the above type of `for loop` since it isn't incremented or decremented like the typical `for loop` is.

Comment: It's a for loop.

Comment: it is a for loop

Comment: I would say it's a for loop though.

Comment: The regular kind

Comment: I guess its just a normal for loop. What you put in between the ";" is optional

Comment: One without a block.

Comment: You should have specified that you were looking for a thread safe way to loop through your object. Increment/decrement doesn't necessarily need to occur via a numeric index as you see here. There really isn't a special name. You would have been better off searching for a Thread Safe looping methods (there are a number of results on SO for this). This question was downvoted due to lack of research effort. The bitter comment about the downvotes doesn't help matters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I should have started off with that from the beginning. The bitter comments were from the fact that people just down vote without any sort of constructive feedback. This site is supposed to be about helping people but I sometimes feel that people lose site of that and just downvote because they can. I will try to do a better job phrasing my questions in the future.

Comment: Yes...it should be about helping.

Answer (score 4):

It reads an EventRecord with the first logReader.ReadEvent,

```
for(EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent(); ....
```

then checks if this instance is null,

```
for(.....;eventdetail != null;....)
```

then executes the body of the for loop and then ask again for another EventRecord.

```
for(.....;.....;eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent())
```

and again checks if the return is null. This continues until the EventRecord returned by ReadEvent is null.

It is smart but I would prefer a more readable while loop

```
while((EventRecord eventdetail = logReader.ReadEvent()) != null)
{
   .....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no special name. It just an ordinary run of the mill `for loop`.
It has an initializatin-clause,condition-clause,iteration-clause.

For what its worth...any on of the clause can be omitted!
I.E. `For(;;)` will create an infinite loop.

[for statement (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for)